# Datagridview and DataError

Tags: visual-studio-2012, datagridview

I am using a DataGridView with a dataset as a source. I have setup a dataset within visual studio and it all works well.

One column is an integer and if you enter something that is not, the DataError event fires and lets me know. Great! (e.context is 768)

Another column is a string, but unique. Again the event fires but there is a difference.. (e.context is 512)

The Integer column fires as soon as finish editing the cell.
The String column with unique only fires when I click off the row, not the cell.
The issue is the e.Column index doesn't relate to the cell with the error. It is what ever I click on.

I had previously used a manual way of checking for unique values, but had hoped this more automatic way would suit better. Is there any way to get the DataError to trigger after every cell?

Is there another way to work with unique values?

Many thanks

EDIT

Sorry if I wasn't clear...

If I have a INT column and I put a letter in as soon as I confirm the value (press enter/click out of the column) I get the DataError trigger.

If I have a STRING column set to Unique if I then enter a value that already exists in the column I only get the trigger once I confirm the ROW (click off the row)

I feel manual coding might be easier and then I can make it work exactly like I want!

Does that make sense?
Cheers

Comment: You should clarify your question. Your comment is unclear… _”Another column is a string, but unique. Again the event fires but there is a difference…”_? I cannot imagine “why” you would get a `DataError` from a string/text column. If the column is a `string/text` column, then its “uniqueness” is something “your” code is going to have to check. The same would apply to “any” column of data.

Comment: Example, if you have an ID column that is a “unique key/primary key” column in the database, then when you “load” that data into the grid… the grid will obligingly allow the user to enter “new” ID’s that are NOT unique. The grid is not going to care about this “uniqueness” unless “your” code checks for it. If it doesn’t, then, you will most likely get a “duplicate key” error when you attempt to “insert” the non-unique ID into the data base.

Comment: The grids `DataError` exception is “usually” thrown when the user attempts to add data to a column that is the wrong “type.” Like adding alpha text to an `int` column or an invalid date to a date column. However as mentioned previously, I am not sure “what” would cause a string/text column to throw the `DataError`. Can you clarify what you mean by _“but there is a difference”_?